# how to break text in field when copy to notepad in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use char(13) and char(10) for break text in sql server.

I want when copy text filed content top the notepad , text in break.
I use below code to break line :

```
declare @result varchar(30)='this is some'+ char(13)+char(10)+'text'
```

but when I copy text to notepad all text show in a line .
how can I do this ?

I searched in google , but cant find any similar answer.

Comment: have you tried with only one of them!?? not both together. I mean one time also try with char(10) or char(13) not both

Comment: one time check with `char(13)` and one time `char(10)` . but i dont getting any result .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it have to work:

just try this one, (using only one of `char(13)` or `char(10)` also gives same output)

```
declare @result varchar(30)='this is some'+char(13)+char(10)+'text'
print @result
```

*Output:*(copied exact output from my window)

```
this is some
text
```

but for getting the result to notepad(windows) don't copy/past from the displayed grid within management studio use `xp_cmdshell` as below:

```
master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT ''this is some''+char(13)+char(10)+''text''" queryout C:\myText.txt -t, -c -Slocalhost -T'
```

*exact content:*

```
this is some
text
```

**Note:** you may need to enable xp_cmdshell:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: How can use Veriable from static text . I want Replace `''this text''` with a Variable like as `@txt`